Show there is some $c>0$ satisfying $\frac{1}{|\cosh(\pi z)|}<\frac{c}{1+(\Re(z))^2}$
I ran into the following problem in my complex analysis textbook:
Let $0<\alpha<1/2$. Show there is a constant $c>0$ such that in the horizontal strip $|\Im(z)|<\alpha$, the following holds:
$$\frac{1}{|\cosh(\pi z)|}<\frac{c}{1+\Re(z)^2}$$
I tried to use the exponential definition of the hyperbolic cosine paired with the following fact: $|e^z|=\Re(e^z)$. It led me nowhere. Any hints would be greatly appreciated !

For $z=x + i y$ is
$$
 \cosh(\pi z) = \cosh(\pi x) \cos(\pi y) + i \sinh(\pi x) \sin(\pi y)
$$
and therefore
$$
|\cosh(\pi z)| \ge |\operatorname{Re}(\cosh(\pi z)| = \cosh(\pi x)\cdot| \cos(\pi y)| \, .
$$
If $|y| < \alpha < 1/2$ then
$$
 |\cosh(\pi z)| >  \cosh(\pi x) \cos(\pi \alpha)
\ge (1 + \frac 12 \pi^2 x^2) \cos(\pi \alpha) \\
\ge (1+ x^2) \cos(\pi \alpha) 
$$
from which the desired inequality follows, with $c = 1/\cos(\pi \alpha)> 0$.
